# Preventing code entries containing malicious shell script

Tags: c++, node.js, linux, security, amazon-ec2

I'm creating a programming platform, where people are given c++ programming tasks, their code gets uploaded to Amazon linux EC2 instance, compiled, executed and compared to expected output.

What measures should I take to prevent people from writing malicious code, which could, for example, delete everything from EC2 instance? Would dockerizing compilation/execution process be sufficient?

Comment: Perhaps ... but you are asking to opinions about professional services (which is why I voted to close this question).

Comment: Forget to mention, that the project is completely educational and non profit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm creating a programming platform, where people are given c++ programming tasks, their code gets uploaded to Amazon linux EC2 instance, compiled, executed and compared to expected output.

If you're a professor who checks your student code i think github education (https://classroom.github.com/) is good for you and implement github actions to test the output of the program.

> Would dockerizing compilation/execution process be sufficient?

It's good enough. just to be sure run the program inside the container without root permission.

Comment: I'm a student and this platform is being made for high school students to use as an educational tool. Just a small side project:) Thank you for the answer!